# New Version of Spring-integration-aws in Maven

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, spring-integration

I am able to find spring-integration-aws of version 0.5.0. Is there a latest release with Spring 4.0 and Spring Integration 4.0 available to be used?

I cannot find it in Maven repo.

Regards
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

Nope. It's really top my priority task from the next several weeks just after the the [SpringOne](http://www.springone2gx.com/) conference.

Meanwhile you can use something like this before the official `RELEASE`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-aws</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

From the http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/ repository.

Comment: Cool Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I tested the version you provided, it works. But if I need to set a proxy for it to access, how do I set it? I could not find an option. Thanks and Appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, not sure. Do you mean something like Nexus?

Comment: I am referring to the proxy to be used within my network to connect to AWS like providing s3 client configuration using com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration (Spring Cloud-AWS).

Comment: Well, looks like this is one of those critical requests for the Spring Integration AWS improvement: we really need to move our S3 adapters to the `s-c-aws` foundation. Meanwhile I see only the way to extend `AbstractAmazonS3Operations` with your logic to inject `ClientConfiguration` for the `AmazonS3Client`. Feel free to raise a JIRA ticket on the matter.

Comment: Thanks for your time and appreciated!

Comment: I created the JIRA INTEXT-194 - https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT-194?jql=project%20%3D%20INTEXT%20AND%20component%20%3D%20AWS%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20priority%20%3D%20Minor%20ORDER%20BY%20key%20DESC

Comment: I took the code and based on your feedback I modified the org/springframework/integration/aws/config/xml/spring-integration-aws-1.0.xsd, org.springframework.integration.aws.s3.config.xml.AmazonS3InboundChannelAdapterParser to parse the proxy host and port, org.springframework.integration.aws.s3.AmazonS3InboundSynchronizationMessageSource to add a condition to inject ClientConfiguration as another constructor argument to DefaultAmazonS3Operations (added a new Constructor). I tested it works with this changes. Let me know your feedback.

Comment: That sounds awesome! I'd like to see something like that as a contribution, but already based on the spring-cloud-awe foundation :-)

Comment: Yes, I used the same fundamentals like spring cloud aws. Would you like me to do a Pull request?

Comment: Yes that would be great. I don't have power today to code. But I can review:-)!

Comment: can you please let me know when is the timeline for GA version release of this component? Just to see to plan for my release as we are planning to use this component to create custom s3 source and sink for SpringXD.